# $env:homedrive is lost occasionally

Tags: powershell, azure

I use `$env:homedrive` in my scripts in Azure's CustomScriptExtension.
Strangely sometimes I got blank from this variable but sometimes OK.

Is this environment variable not reliable?

Comment: Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may be the environment variable, it may be something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's difficult to say without looking at the script. But you can put a $null condition check before proceeding.

> ```
> if($env:HOMEDRIVE -eq $null){
>   $env:HOMEDRIVE = "H:" # Whatever you want
> }
> else{
>   Do-WhatYouWant
> }
> ```

2. Alternative you can set `$env:HOMEDRIVE` directly to your desired location at the beginning of the script or function. But still, I would prefer to put the $null check condition always.
   @Dave Wu

Answer (score 0):

If it concerns a script at logon, it is possible that network is not loaded yet due to [windows fast logon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573586(v=ws.11).aspx). Maybe directly pulling it from the registry is more reliable:

```
(Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue "HKCU:\Volatile Environment").GetValue("HomeDrive")
```